# OpenCV modules as a symbolic link causes cmake errors

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:232 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "C:/dev/opencv/modules/ascend" which is not
  an existing directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
```

where i created teh module as a symbolic link

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mklink /D "C:\dev\opencv\modules\ascend" "C:\dev\AscendProje
cts\AscendPipeline\opencv_ascend"
symbolic link created for C:\dev\opencv\modules\ascend <<===>> C:\dev\AscendProj
ects\AscendPipeline\opencv_ascend
```

is it not possible to work around this in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV CMake script has `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` option, which allows to set path to optinal modules. You don't have to create sumbolic links:

```
cd <opencv_build_directory>
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:\dev\AscendProjects\AscendPipeline .
```

Comment: Do you know if there is something like this also for example programs.

Comment: Extra modules can have `samples` sub-folder with applications. You can find some examples if such extra modules here : https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed. Development is so much easier when putting our own code into a module and using cmake to generate the visual studio solution. Setting up all the dependencies manually is a pain. Thanks for the help

Comment: It works if I have my .cpp file under the samples folder but if I create a /samples/mysample.cps stucture its not generated in the solution file. I want the folder such I can create more samples with different CMakeList.txt files to add additional dependencies outside opencv